# Excel row-column conversion using Java

Tags: java, python, apache-poi

Folks,

Am looking for some help to create a standalone utility to convert the input sheet below into an output format given below. Am interested to do this in Java, any pointers is appreciated

## Input sheet

```
DATE        Item1   Item2 
31-Mar-2000 8.6     3.8 
03-Apr-2000 8.6     3.8 
04-Apr-2000 8.6     3.8 
05-Apr-2000 8.6     3.8
```

## Output sheet

```
DATE        ITEMS VALUE
31-Mar-2000 ITEM1 8.6
03-Apr-2000 ITEM1 8.6
04-Apr-2000 ITEM1 8.6
05-Apr-2000 ITEM1 8.6
31-Mar-2000 ITEM2 3.8
03-Apr-2000 ITEM2 3.8
04-Apr-2000 ITEM2 3.8
05-Apr-2000 ITEM2 3.8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/)

Here is an example of how to read and write [Excel files](http://howtodoinjava.com/apache-commons/readingwriting-excel-files-in-java-poi-tutorial/)

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, but am looking more specific like reverse pivot table as shown in [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3wWQjRWkJc) , this need to be done in Java in a more automated way for any given excel sheet

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little awk script that did the trick , doing it in java involves lot of coding.

## Awk script below.

```
BEGIN {
    FS = ","
    OFS = ","
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
(NR == 1) {
    for (i=2;i<NF;i++) {
        hdr[i-1]=$i;
    }
    print $1,"ID","VALUE"
}

(NR > 1) {
    dt=$1
    for (i=2;i<NF;i++) {
        print dt,hdr[i-1],$i
    }
}
```